# "org.apache.catalina.startup.Tool main GRAVE: Must set 'catalina.home' system property" when CATALINA_HOME variable is already set

Tags: java, eclipse

Hi I'm having a problem starting a webapp with Tomcat; I've read around for different solutions, but can't find anyone else with the same problem! I think it's something pretty basic, but I just can't find it for the life of me.

```
org.apache.catalina.startup.Tool main
GRAVE: Must set 'catalina.home' system property
```

The problem is though, I have set the CATALINA_HOME variable:

[Environment Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOQuQ.png)

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: How are you starting the tomcat?

Comment: I use %CATALINA_HOME%\bin\startup.bat from run